# C++ namespace: using without owning

Tags: c++, namespaces, using

I want to use stuff from another namespace in my namespace, without making it part of my namespace. More concrete I have the following situation:

```cpp
namespace my_ns{
    enum class c: unsigned long long int{};

    namespace literals{
        constexpr c operator"" _c(unsigned long long int i)noexcept{
            return c(i);
        }
    }

    using namespace literals;

    auto xyz = 4_c; // OK: use literals::operator""_c
}

void some_function(){
    using namespace my_ns; // shall not implicit include my_ns::literals!

    auto abc = xyz; // OK
    auto def = 4_c; // shall not know my_ns::literals::operator""_c
}
```

I want to use the user literals in `my_ns` but for consistency with `std` and `std::literals` not in `some_function` after the `using namespace`. Do you think the consistency argument is worth the headaches?

And if it is, is there a way to do it or to do something similar?

Comment: The answer is simple: don't blow away your namespaces with using directives.

Comment: The question is begged: why create a custom literal if you're not going to let anyone use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a nested `detail` namespace and then expose only what you want to the main `my_ns` namespace:

```
namespace my_ns
{
    namespace detail
    {
        using namespace literals;
        auto xyz = 4_c; // OK: use literals::operator""_c
    }

    using detail::xyz;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another namespace and then expose it for all

```
namespace Rtos
{
  constexpr unsigned long long operator "" ms(unsigned long long ms) 
  {
    return ms / portTICK_PERIOD_MS ; 
  } ;
}

namespace GlobalVars
{
  using Rtos::operator""ms ;
  Rtos::Event event{1000ms, 1} ;
}

using GlobalVars::event ;

void SomeFunction()
{
  event.Signal();
}
```